# How to compile ADF and JSF Utils and create the JAR files?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I would like to compile the [ADF and JSF Utils](https://blogs.oracle.com/OTN-Issues/entry/adf_and_jsf_utils_clasees) and make a jar file containing the two so that I can make use of it in my ADF Applications.

Please let me know if you have done this before (couldn't find a step by step tutorial).

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: The [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) has a section on creating jar files.

Comment: Create a new java project . add the files and deploy as jar?

Comment: In JDev, create a new deployment profile of type .jar in project containing utils. Edit profile and set Contributors to Project Source Path only. In Filters section, select those .java files. Deploy using that profile.